# How to make xml schema relate(link) to JTable,xml java?

Tags: java, swing, jaxb, xsd, jtable

Here you can see my application:
[image]

**So what i need to do:**

I dont know how I can through code link xml schema with JTable with all type(int,string,float). Say like Year is type int and in schema is int and how i can link it? I dont know how will be in english link or relate.
In this application i write all data to xml file, and when application loaded it loads all data from xml file.

Here i creating xml schema:

```
      public void CreateSchema(String FileName){

        file=FileName;
        JAXBContext jc;
        try {
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlSchemaType.class);

                jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

                    @Override
                    public javax.xml.transform.Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName)throws IOException {
                        suggestedFileName=file+".xsd";
                        return new StreamResult(suggestedFileName);
                    }

                });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }
```

Here is all types:

```
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlRootElement(name = "Auto")
   public class XmlSchemaType {
    row[] Row;
   }


   class row {
    @XmlAttribute
    byte ID;

    @XmlElement
    String VIN;
    @XmlElement
    String Make;
    @XmlElement
    String Model;
    @XmlElement
    int Year;
    @XmlElement
    String Description;
    @XmlElement
    float Cost;
   }
```

Here is writing to xml file:

```
public void CreateXml(JTable tb,JTable tb2,String FileName){
      try {

        file=FileName;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Auto");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);


        int i=0,j=0,k=0;

        while (i<tb.getRowCount()){

            j=0;
            Element rows = doc.createElement("Row");
            rootElement.appendChild(rows);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue((i+1)+"");
            rows.setAttributeNode(attr);

            //Pirma lentele
            while (j<tb.getColumnCount()-1){

                Element element = doc.createElement(tb.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getHeaderValue()+"");
                element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(tb.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+""));
                rows.appendChild(element);

                j++;
            }

            //Antra lentele
            j=2;//pirmu lauku nereikia
            while (j<tb2.getColumnCount()-1){
                        Element element2 = doc.createElement(tb2.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getHeaderValue()+"");
                        element2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(tb2.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+""));
                        rows.appendChild(element2); 
                        if (j==2){
                                tb2.getModel().setValueAt(tb.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0),i,1);  

                        }

                j++;
            }



            i++;
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result;
        try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File(file+".xml"));


        result = new StreamResult(fileOutputStream);//new FileOutputStream(file+".xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");//new line... kad butu naujoje eiluteje
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
      //file.renameTo(FileName+".xml");

   }
```

And here loading my xml file:

```
    public void PopulateDataSet(JTable tb,JTable tb2,String FileName){


      file=FileName;
      File f= new File(file+".xml");
      if (f.exists()){ 
          try {
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tb.getModel();
                    model.addRow(new Object[] { "", "","","","Delete" });
                    tb.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("VIN").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 0);
                    tb.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Make").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 1);
                    tb.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Make").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 2);
                    tb.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Year").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 3);
                    tb.getModel().setValueAt("Delete",temp, 4);

                    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) tb2.getModel();
                    model2.addRow(new Object[] { (tb2.getRowCount()+1), "","","","Delete" });
                     tb2.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("VIN").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 1);
                    tb2.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 2);
                    tb2.getModel().setValueAt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Cost").item(0).getTextContent(),temp, 3);
                    tb2.getModel().setValueAt("Delete",temp, 4);

                }

            }

          } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
      }
      if (!f.exists()){ 
          CreateXml(tb,tb2,file);
          CreateSchema(file); 
      }


  }
```

But how to use xml shema with JTable, xml?

Comment: What do you want from XML Schema?  XML-based validation?  JAXB-style class mapping with marshalling/unmarshalling support?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Here is writing to xml file:"* ---- *"And here loading my xml file:"*

Why are you using DOM to read and write the xml, when you are already using JAXB Mapping. If you are doing the mapping correctly <sup>**1**</sup>, it's just a matter of using the [**`Marshaller`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) and [**`Unmarshaller`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) to write and read, respectively. Make sure to look at those API links yo see example usage. It's only around 5 lines of code to handle each operaion.

<sub>**(1)** Please see the [JAXB tutorial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html) for more info about JAXB mapping.</sub>

Also, you can just create your own [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and unmarshal and marshal straight to and from the table model. This is probably the most effective way to keep everything sync. Create a class `Auto` to represent each row, and a class `AutoModel`, that will be the root element in the xml document, as well as the `TableModel` for the `JTable`. Something like:

`Auto` class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Auto", propOrder = {
        "id", "VIN", "Make", "Model", "Year", "Description", "Cost"
})
public class Auto {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    Integer id;
    @XmlElement(name = "VIN")
    String VIN;
    @XmlElement(name = "Make")
    String Make;
    @XmlElement(name = "Model")
    String Model;
    @XmlElement(name = "Year")
    Integer Year;
    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    String Description;
    @XmlElement(name = "Cost")
    Float Cost;

    // === DON'T FORGET YOUR GETTERS and SETTERS
}
```

`AutoModel` class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AutoList")
public class AutoModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    String[] columnNames = {"VIN", "Make", "Model", "Year"};

    @XmlElement(name = "Auto")
    protected List<Auto> autos;

    public AutoModel() {
        autos = new ArrayList<Auto>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return autos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return columnNames[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Auto auto = autos.get(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0 : value = auto.getVIN(); break;
            case 1 : value = auto.getMake(); break;
            case 2 : value = auto.getModel(); break;
            case 3 : value = auto.getYear(); break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

`Test`, using this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AutoList>
    <Auto>
        <id>1</id>
        <VIN>123456788910FASDE</VIN>
        <Make>Mercedes</Make>
        <Model>CL 550</Model>
        <Year>2012</Year>
        <Description>Hello World</Description>
        <Cost>80000.00</Cost>
    </Auto>
</AutoList>
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class TestTableMarshall {

    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "src/table/autos.xml";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "src/table/autos1.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AutoModel model = unmarshal(INPUT_FILE);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
        marshal(model, OUTPUT_FILE);

    }

    private static void marshal(AutoModel model, String file) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AutoModel.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        File f= new File(file);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(model, f);
    }

    private static AutoModel unmarshal(String file) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AutoModel.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        AutoModel model = (AutoModel)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(file));
        return model;
    }
}
```

---

As far the the `AutoModel` goes, it only works for your first table. You will need to create another model for your repairs table. Also, the model, currently only offered read-only. You will need to add other functionality to say add a row and set individual values.

Here are some resources to look at:

- [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- [JAXB Specification toturial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html)

---

**NOTE:** With the JAXB annotations above you can create the schema, and you you want to validate the xml against it, you could just set the schema when you unmarshal. Something like:

```
private static AutoModel unmarshal(String file) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AutoModel.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("src/table/autos.xsd"));
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    AutoModel model = (AutoModel)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(file));
    return model;
}
```