# How to write a JTable state with data in xml file using XMLEndcoder in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, xmlencoder

I want to save `JTable` in xml file using `XMLEncoder`.
When we are saving it into a file, getting an exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: XMLEncoder: discarding statement ColorPropertyTable.removeMouseMotionListener(BasicTableUI$Handler);
Continuing ...
```

Comment: you would need to save value (from JTable, better from XxxTableModel) not JTable, required iterating in rows and columns

Comment: See [TableModel - JAXB example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25966347/2587435). May be of interest

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on aterai's example. It is a little more complete because it will also persist the column names:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest
{
    private File file = new File("TableModel.xml");
    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    private final String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column2"};

    private final Object[][] data =
    {
        {"aaa", new Integer(1)},
        {"bbb\u2600", new Integer(2)}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    private final JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public JComponent makeUI()
    {
        model.setColumnCount(5);
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        sp.setResizeWeight(.3);
        sp.setTopComponent(new JScrollPane(table));
        sp.setBottomComponent(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLEncoder")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    XMLEncoder xe = new XMLEncoder(os);
                    xe.setPersistenceDelegate(DefaultTableModel.class, new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate2());
                    xe.writeObject(model);
                    xe.close();

                    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
                    textArea.read(r, null);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLDecoder")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ));
                    XMLDecoder xd = new XMLDecoder(is);
                    model = (DefaultTableModel)xd.readObject();
                    table.setModel(model);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("clear")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                model = new DefaultTableModel();
                table.setModel(model);
            }
        }));

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnl.add(sp);
        pnl.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return pnl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest().makeUI());
        f.setSize(420, 340);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

//http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html

class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate extends DefaultPersistenceDelegate
{
    //  Initially creates an empty DefaultTableModel. The columns are created
    //  and finally each row of data is added to the model.

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Class<?> type, Object oldInstance, Object newInstance, Encoder encoder)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)oldInstance;

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(model.getColumnCount());

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            columnNames.add( model.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        Object[] columnNamesData = new Object[] { columnNames };
        encoder.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "setColumnIdentifiers", columnNamesData));

        Vector row = model.getDataVector();

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[] { row.get(i) };
            encoder.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "addRow", rowData));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html
>   **Registering for Exception Notifications**
>   Both XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder catch exceptions and are typically able to recover from them, allowing the parts of the archive **not affected by the exception to be written or read**. You can find out more about any exceptions raised in the encoding and decoding processes by registering an ExceptionListener as follows:
>   ...

[image]

*Example*

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest {
  private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

  private final String[] columnNames = {"A", "B"};
  private final Object[][] data = {
    {"aaa", "ccccccc"}, {"bbb", "\u2600\u2601\u2602\u2603"}
  };
  private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
  private final JTable table = new JTable(model);

  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    sp.setResizeWeight(.5);
    sp.setTopComponent(new JScrollPane(table));
    sp.setBottomComponent(new JScrollPane(textArea));

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLEncoder") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
          File file = File.createTempFile("output", ".xml");
          try (OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            XMLEncoder xe = new XMLEncoder(os);
            xe.setPersistenceDelegate(
                DefaultTableModel.class, new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate());
//          xe.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
//              @Override public void exceptionThrown(Exception exception) {
//                  //XXX: exception.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          });
//          xe.writeObject(table);
            xe.writeObject(model);
            //xe.flush();
            xe.close();
          }
          try (Reader r = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))) {
            textArea.read(r, "temp");
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLDecoder") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(textArea.getText().getBytes("UTF-8")))) {
          XMLDecoder xd = new XMLDecoder(is);
          model = (DefaultTableModel) xd.readObject();
          table.setModel(model);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("clear") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table.setModel(model);
      }
    }));

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pnl.add(sp);
    pnl.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return pnl;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
//http://web.archive.org/web/20090806075316/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/
//http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html
class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate extends DefaultPersistenceDelegate {
  @Override protected void initialize(
      Class<?> type, Object oldInstance, Object newInstance, Encoder encoder) {
    super.initialize(type, oldInstance,  newInstance, encoder);
    DefaultTableModel m = (DefaultTableModel) oldInstance;
//         Vector v = m.getDataVector();
//         for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++) {
//             encoder.writeStatement(
//               new Statement(oldInstance, "addRow", new Object[] { (Vector) v.get(i) }));
//         }
    for (int row = 0; row < m.getRowCount(); row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < m.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        Object[] o = new Object[] {m.getValueAt(row, col), row, col};
        encoder.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "setValueAt", o));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi aterai, xml file not created.

Comment: @ArvindSingh I fixed the suffix.