# Load data from txt file to JTable

Tags: java, jtable, save, load

Is there any easy way to **load** data from txt file, if **saving** data from JTable to txt file look like:

```
for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        out.println(table.getColumnName(col));
                        out.print(": ");
                        out.println(table.getValueAt(row, col));
```

Or maybe is another way to keep data in JTable if user Exit program and run again?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: if necessary more code, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

You could look into serializing the JTable. Which is a built in process of Saving an entire object to a file.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: thanks for hint. I will check this and help if will work

Comment: You probably don't want to use serialization. There is a "warning" in the API for all Swing components that serialization is not appropriate for long term storage as it may not be compatible for release to release. Instead you should use the XMLEncoder.

Comment: I check java docs and Jtable implements java.io.Serializable but JTableModel not. So like you say, I cant use Serializable

Answer (score 1):

Since JDK 4 you can use the `XMLEncoder` to provide permanent storage and the `XMLDecoder` to recreate the object you are saving. You need to create a `PersistenceDelegate` to aid in the encoding and decoding of the data.

Here is an example for the `DefaultTableModel`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest
{
    private File file = new File("TableModel.xml");
    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    private final String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column2"};

    private final Object[][] data =
    {
        {"aaa", new Integer(1)},
        {"bbb\u2600", new Integer(2)}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    private final JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public JComponent makeUI()
    {
        model.setColumnCount(5);
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        sp.setResizeWeight(.3);
        sp.setTopComponent(new JScrollPane(table));
        sp.setBottomComponent(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLEncoder")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    XMLEncoder xe = new XMLEncoder(os);
                    xe.setPersistenceDelegate(DefaultTableModel.class, new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate2());
                    xe.writeObject(model);
                    xe.close();

                    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
                    textArea.read(r, null);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("XMLDecoder")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ));
                    XMLDecoder xd = new XMLDecoder(is);
                    model = (DefaultTableModel)xd.readObject();
                    table.setModel(model);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("clear")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                model = new DefaultTableModel();
                table.setModel(model);
            }
        }));

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnl.add(sp);
        pnl.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return pnl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegateTest().makeUI());
        f.setSize(420, 340);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

//http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html

class DefaultTableModelPersistenceDelegate extends DefaultPersistenceDelegate
{
    //  Initially creates an empty DefaultTableModel. The columns are created
    //  and finally each row of data is added to the model.

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Class<?> type, Object oldInstance, Object newInstance, Encoder encoder)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)oldInstance;

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(model.getColumnCount());

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            columnNames.add( model.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        Object[] columnNamesData = new Object[] { columnNames };
        encoder.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "setColumnIdentifiers", columnNamesData));

        Vector row = model.getDataVector();

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[] { row.get(i) };
            encoder.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "addRow", rowData));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is a more complete example of the solution found in: [How to write a JTable state with data in xml file using XMLEndcoder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250939/how-to-write-a-jtable-state-with-data-in-xml-file-using-xmlendcoder-in-java)

The text area in the example is just used to show the contents of the XML file for the data being saved.