# Save JTable Values After Insert Them

Tags: java, jtable, save

After I insert some values in a JTable and close the app all the values dissapear.
How do I do to save the values even if the app closes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write the data to a file. Then when the program restarts you read the data from the file back into the table. So you can add a WindowListener to the frame to invoke the logic to save the data when the frame closes.

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for examples of how to invoke code when the frame is closed.

Check out: [Saving content of Interactive JTable to .txt file to read it upon next run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432538/saving-content-of-interactive-jtable-to-txt-file-to-read-it-upon-next-run/31434084#31434084) for a generic solution for saving and restoring the data.

Put the two concepts together of a possible solution.