# Serialize JTable's TableModel

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtable, tablemodel

I need to send the content of a `JTable` to a REST Service. For this purpose, I'd like to send the `TableModel` to the REST Service. However, I can see that the `TableModel` class is not `Serializable`.

Is there any other option other than copying the `TableModel` in a wrapper Java class (`Serializable`)?

Comment: I wouldnt send the tablemodel. I would send the array list that you define inside the tablemodel.

Comment: DefaultTableModel that you're probably going to use *IS* serializable. TableModel is just an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually table's row is dto. So you need send just collection of dtos using available marshallers (json, xml etc).

Comment: +1 For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418826/2587435), and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26527403/2587435)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I'll cast the model to DefaultTableModel and send the Vector contained in getDataVector() using marshallers.

Comment: Or [JAXB example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25966347/2587435) (above was using JSON and Jackson)